# Wood to be used for Christmas Colored Flame Yule Logs?

Tags: wood

What type of wood and its' thickness would be get the best results for making **Christmas colored flame yule logs**?

I would like to try and make colored flamed yule logs this year. What type of wood would get the maximum amount of absorption of the (chemical) mixture of colored solution into the wood? What would be the thickest circumference that would enable the colored flames last the longest?

Most internet sources suggest tightly bound newspaper, wood chips or pine cones. I would like to do the same using wood in the form of small logs, in order to make it resemble a real Christmas yule log for the fireplace. They may take up to a month to dry, prior to using.

**Helpful Sources:**

[How to Make Colored Fire](https://www.popsci.com/diy/article/2007-11/how-make-colored-fire)

[The History of the Yule Log](https://www.whychristmas.com/customs/yulelog.shtml)

[Add Color to Fireplace Flames for Christmas](https://www.motherearthnews.com/homesteading-and-livestock/add-color-to-fireplace-flames-zmaz77ndzgoe)

[Yule log (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yule_log)

Comment: I hope this question is not too simplistic, but I really do not know my wood and our forests and parks have lots of downed branches.

Comment: Note that this is cross posted from [Arts&Crafts](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/q/4262/319) where it's received more attention, so this is probably be closed as cross posting is frowned upon, but I can't flag it as a dupe on another site

Comment: Flagging as off-topic since it is a duplicate of https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/4262/wood-used-for-christmas-colored-flame-yule-logs and has upvotes and an answer there